# How to get the div you want to delete by using its name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've saved the name of the DIV I want to delete in a variable with JQuery.
I want to delete this div with JQuery. I tried this code:

```
var list = $('#myLists .list').attr('name') == oberpname; //oberpname is the variable with the name
        for (index = list.length - 1; index >= 0; index--){
            list[index].parentNode.removeChild((list[index]));
        }

//$oberpname has the same name as in oberpname in JQuery above
<div id="myLists">
   <div class="list" name=$oberpname></div> 
</div>
```

When I run this code nothing happens. How can I refert exactly to div with JQuery?

EDIT NOTE:

Deleted some mistakes like the ID.

Comment: For the above code you could simply use `$("#list").remove()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your markup is invalid. Add name attribute value in quotes.and use:

```
$('#myLists div[name="oberpname"]').remove()
```

or from variable:

```
$('#myLists div[name="'+oberpname+'"]').remove()
```

Comment: Do I have to use [name="'+oberpname+'"] when oberpname is a variable

Answer (score 3):

Use [Attribute Equals Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)  and than [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

```
$('#myLists div[name="oberpname"]').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
var oberpname = "somename";
$('div[name=' + oberpname + ']').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use:

```
$('#myLists div[name=oberpname]').remove();
```

instead of looping like what you're doing at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

for correctness, the element div does not have the "name" attribute. you may use id, class, or data-*, such as data-name.

```
<div class="list" data-name="custom-name">
    ...
</div>
```

if using data-name (assuming oberpname='custom-name'),

```
$('#myLists [data-name="'+oberpname+'"]').remove()
```

I'm not sure why you want to use variable in the HTML, as you can't do it like the one in your example. If you want to assign a variable for data-name via jQuery, you should target the element with a specific class then add attribute.

```
<div class="list">
</div>
```

your script should look like:

```
var customName = 'custom-name';

$('.list').attr('data-name',customName);

$('#myLists [data-name="'+customName+'"]').remove()
```

Comment: In my project I don't have only one div. The divs will be added dynamcially by clicking on checkboxes. That's why I can't use just the HTML. In the variable oberpname is the name of the checkbox saved - I use the same value for the div, so I can easily find out which div belongs to which checkbox. If I uncheck the checkbox, it should delete the one div with the same value and not all divs. What's the difference between "name" and "data-name" - the name tag worked for me.

Comment: although the attribute "name" works for div, it is not technically correct as there is no "name" attribute for div (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes). It really is a minor thing, but if you want to keep a clean code, using proper attributes for specific elements is a good start.

the "name" attribute is primarily used in anchors(<a>) and input fields (<input>)

Comment: I get your point regarding using specific variables for certain div elements, but you can't put a variable in the html like this <div name=$oberpname>. it just won't work as HTML alone won't process that variable. you would have to do it via javascript. what you can do is have a code that assigns class name when a certain checkbox is clicked.

Comment: I don't have "HTML-only" Code in my project. I always output my HTML-Code with PHP. So I prevent those errors. I actually don't want to specify unique classes for each div or checkbox because I will later implement a function, which gets all the checked boxes of this one class. So it's actually good so. My code works fine now. Thank you for some tips!